# Javascript function not running on pod creation using a Kubernetes Job

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have an AKS cluster with a Node.js server and a mongo db. I want to create MongoDb records from a repair catalog in a json file using the server endpoint.

To do so I created an Helm chart , with the `sendRepiarData.js` and the `catalog.json` files under a `files` folder and a `Job` which should create a Node pod and run the `sendRepiarData.js` file.

When I install the chart the Job does create the pod and set the status to completed but no data is sent to the server and I don't get any logs from the pod when I run the `kubectl logs` command on that pod.

So to debug it I commented out the function and just printed to console, but still no logs from the pod. I'm fairly new to Kubernetes and I guess I'm misconfiguring the Job's volumeMounts a volumes parameters.
Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks.

## Events:

```
8s          Normal   Scheduled              pod/fixit-repair-catalog-job-pzcb5                Successfully assigned default/fixit-repair-catalog-job-pzcb5 to aks-default-80269438-vmss000000
8s          Normal   Pulled                 pod/fixit-repair-catalog-job-pzcb5                Container image "node:14" already present on machine
8s          Normal   Created                pod/fixit-repair-catalog-job-pzcb5                Created container fixit-repair-catalog-job
8s          Normal   Started                pod/fixit-repair-catalog-job-pzcb5                Started container fixit-repair-catalog-job
8s          Normal   SuccessfulCreate       job/fixit-repair-catalog-job                      Created pod: fixit-repair-catalog-job-pzcb5
4s          Normal   Completed              job/fixit-repair-catalog-job                      Job completed
```

## .Values:

```
replicaCount: 1
global:
  namespace: default
image:
  repository: node
  tag: 14

# filePath: .
filePath: "/files"
service:
  name: fixit-repair-catalog
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 3000


fullnameOverride: ""
```

## Job:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-job
  labels:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Release.Name }}-job
          image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}
          command: ["node"]
          args: [ {{ .Files.Get "/files/sendRepairData.js" }} ]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: repair-catalog
              mountPath: /app/files
      volumes:
        - name: repair-catalog
          hostPath:
            path: {{ .Values.filePath }}
```

## sendRepairData.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');

// Function to send repair data
var savedRepairs = [];
function sendRepairData() {
  // Read the catalog JSON file
  try {
    const catalogData = fs.readFileSync('catalog.json'); 
    const catalog = JSON.parse(catalogData);

    // Access the repairs array from the catalog
    const repairs = catalog.repairs;

    // Process the repairs data as needed
    for (const repair of repairs) {
      const options = {
        host: 'server-clusterip-service', 
        port: 3000,
        path: 'api/server/repairs',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          AuthToken: '', 
          apikey: ''
        },
      };

      const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
        let data = '';

        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
          console.log('Response:', data);
          // save response data for resetting the db in case of error
          savedRepairs.push(JSON.parse(data));

        });
      });

      req.on('error', (error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error.message);
      });

      req.write(JSON.stringify(repair));
      req.end();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error reading catalog file:', error.message);
    throw error;
  }
}


// function to reset the db
function deleteRepairs() {
  savedRepairs.forEach((repair) => {
    const options = {
    host: 'server-clusterip-service', 
    port: 3000, 
    path: `api/server/repairs/${repair.id}`,
    method: 'Delete',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      AuthToken: '',  by your server
      apikey: ''
    },
  };

  const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    let data = '';

    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Response:', data);
    });
  });

  req.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
  });
  req.end();
  });
  
}

function uploadRepairCatalog() {
  try {
    sendRepairData();
  } catch (error){
    deleteRepairs();
    throw error;
  }
}
// uploadRepairCatalog();

console.log('cron job done');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kubernetes, you can't really run an unmodified base image and inject your application through mounts.  I see this as an occasional Docker "pattern" to avoid the one-line installation of Node locally, but in Kubernetes you can't reliably access the host system.  To use Kubernetes effectively, you all but must create a custom image and push it to some registry.

In particular, this block of YAML

```yaml
      volumes:
        - name: repair-catalog
          hostPath:
            path: {{ .Values.filePath }}
```

mounts an arbitrary directory *from whichever Node the Pod is running on*.  It cannot copy content from your local machine; indeed, Kubernetes doesn't track from where a Job might have been submitted, and can't connect back out of the cluster.  In most uses you should avoid `hostPath:` mounts.

Instead you need to create a custom image.  If you're just trying to run this script and it doesn't have any dependencies, the Dockerfile is pretty straightfoward

```bash
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app
COPY sendRepairData.js ./
CMD ["node", "./sendRepairData.js"]
```

You then need to either publish the image or get the image into the cluster somehow.  The generic answer, assuming some external image repository exists, looks like

```bash
docker build -t registry.example.com/send-repair-data:20230526 .
docker push registry.example.com/send-repair-data:20230526
```

In local environments you may be able to get away without the "push" command.  Minikube for example has a way to [directly use an embedded Docker daemon](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/pushing/#1-pushing-directly-to-the-in-cluster-docker-daemon-docker-env) so long as you `eval $(minikube docker-env)` before building; Kind has a documented path to [run a local registry](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/local-registry/).

You need to change your `values.yaml` to point at the image you just built

```yaml
image:
  repository: registry.example.com/send-repair-data
  tag: "20230526"
```

Then in the Job YAML, you don't need to provide the file content or override the command at all, all of these details are already embedded in the image.

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      containers:
        - name: send-repair-data  # this name does not need to be configurable
          image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}
      # the end
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Well I don't want to inject my app into an unmodified base image. I want to create a container from a base image with a .js and a .json, and run the function in the .js file which used the data from the .json file.

If I run  `node  sendRepiarData.js` command from within the `/files` directory it just runs the function in that .js file. I just wanna do the same with a Kubernetes job.

Comment: What does your existing Dockerfile look like, then?  In the question you're running the unmodified `node:14` image.  You need to get your code into the cluster somehow and the best approach for that is in an image, not a volume.

Comment: I don't have one, I wasn't expecting to have to build an app just to run a function once. I kinda just wanted to spin up a Node.js container that runs my function once.

Comment: I am now looking into using a ConfigMap to pass the 2 files to the container as a volume.